setup.py file - package_data is not getting copied to the site-packages
I am trying to create a python package from certain so files wherein I have created a simple function in mylib/mylib.py file and also have __init__.py file which contains the functions from mylib.py file, the issue is in site-packages none of these files are getting copied - neither .py files nor .so files as well.
Structure is as follows:
|-mylib
|----__init__.py
|----mylib.py
|----lib
|----share
|----include
|-setup.py

setup.py contains these lines
...
packages=["mylib"],
package_data={
    "mylib": [
         "**/**/*.so.*",
         "**/*.so.*",
         "**/*.so",
         "**/**/*.so"
    ]
}
...


I do not understand how to proceed further for getting files in the site-packages without which I am not able to use it in python code.
